# Akka Camel netty4 query based communication - one to many

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, akka, netty

I want to connect to a tcp server with proprietary protocol which provides data upon queries.

The tcp data is successfully decoded using Netty4 ServerClientHandler. 
Camel consumer(client mode) is used for connecting to the server.
I can send first query through ServerClientHandler on activation.

Requirement

1. Query for 2000 messages.
2. After processing 1000 messages ask for another 1000(total 3000) messages.
3. Repeat

Problem is after processing 1000 messages there is no way to request another 1000 messages.

I have tried to use Netty4 sync option. But what I need is multiple responses for one request.

I was thinking of using netty4 producer. Is there any way to send one request and receive multiple responses using camel netty4 producer. If it is possible I can route responses through camel actors.

I am going through camel netty source code with no success. If you can provide any starting point it will be really helpful.